# Is it good practice to use reflection in your business logic?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to work on an application that consists of two major parts:

- The business logic part with specific business classes (e.g. Book, Library, Author, ...)
- A generic part that can show Books, Libraries, ... in data grids, map them to a database, ...).

The generic part uses reflection to get the data out of the business classes without the need to write specific data-grid or database logic in the business classes.  This works fine and allows us to add new business classes (e.g. LibraryMember) without the need to adjust the data grid and database logic.

However, over the years, code was added to the business classes that also makes use of reflection to get things done in the business classes.  E.g. if the Author of a Book is changed, observers are called to tell the Author itself that it should add this book to its collection of books written by him (Author.Books).  In these observers, not only the instances are passed, but also information that is directly derived from the reflection (the FieldInfo is added to the observer call so that the caller knows that the field "Author" of the book is changed).

I can clearly see advantages in using reflection in these generic modules (like the data grid or database interface), but it seems to me that using reflection in the business classes is a bad idea.  After all, shouldn't the application work without relying on reflection as much as possible?  Or is the use of reflection the 'normal way of working' in the 21st century?

Is it good practice to use reflection in your business logic?

**EDIT**: Some clarification on the remark of Kirk:

- Imagine that Author implements an observer on Book.
- Book calls all its observers whenever some field of Book changes (like Title, Year, #Pages, Author, ...).  The 'FieldInfo' of the changed field is passed in the observer.
- The Author-observer then uses this FieldInfo to decide whether it is interested in this change.  In this case, if FieldInfo is for the field Author of Book, the Author-Observer will update its own vector of Books.

Comment: You say the `FieldInfo` is passed, but I don't see that you explain how it's used.  Concretely, (aside from passing along info classes, which is relatively innocuous) how is reflection being used?

Comment: Do you use it like the INotifyPropertyChanged interface (usually used in WPF applications for data binding)? Raise event whenever property was set, with the property name?

Comment: @Amittai: No, it's a rather custom, very-specific implementation using reflection.

Comment: I meant, does it serve the same purpose, observing object property changes? maybe you may consider using this powerful interface...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I avoid using reflection. Yes, it makes your program more flexible. But this flexibility comes at a high price: There is no compile-time checking of field names or types or whatever information you're collecting through reflection.

Like many things, it depends on what you're doing. If the nature of your logic is that you NEVER compare the field names (or whatever) found to a constant value, then using reflection is probably a good thing. But if you use reflection to find field names, and then loop through them searching for the fields named "Author" and "Title", you've just created a more-complex simulation of an object with two named fields. And what if you search for "Author" when the field is actually called "AuthorName", or you intend to search for "Author" and accidentally type "Auhtor"? Now you have errors that won't show up until runtime instead of being flagged at compile time.

With hard-coded field names, your IDE can tell you every place that a certain field is used. With reflection ... not so easy to tell. Maybe you can do a text search on the name, but if field names are passed around as variables, it can get very difficult.

I'm working on a system now where the original authors loved reflection and similar techniques. There are all sorts of places where they need to create an instance of a class and instead of just saying "new" and the class, they create a token that they look up in a table to get the class name. What does this gain? Yes, we could change the table to map that token to a different name. And this gains us ... what? When was the last time that you said, "Oh, every place that my program creates an instance of Customer, I want to change to create an instance of NewKindOfCustomer." If you have changes to a class, you change the class, not create a new class but keep the old one around for nostalgia.

To take a similar issue, I make a regular practice of building data entry screens on the fly by asking the database for a list of field names, types, and sizes, and then laying it out from there. This gives me the advantage of using the same program for all the simpler data entry screens -- just pass in the table name as a parameter -- and if a field is added or deleted, zero code change is required. But this only works as long as I don't care what the fields are. Once I start having validations or side effects specific to this screen, the system is more trouble than it's worth, and I'm better off to fall back to more explicit coding.

Comment: Holds true to this day. When things get complex and shit goes wrong, its a less than stimulating experience to wade through reflection code to find hidden runtime issues when types or data changes.

Answer (score 12):

The main danger with Reflection is that the flexibility can escalate into disorganized, unmaintainable code, particularly if more junior devs are used to make changes, who may not fully understand the Reflection code or are so enamored of it that they use it to solve every problem, even when simpler tools would suffice.

My observation has been that over-generalization leads to over-complication.  It gets worse when the actual boundary cases turn out to not be accommodated by the generalized design, requiring hacks to fit in the new features on schedule, transmuting flexibility into complexity.

Answer (score 3):

I tend not to use reflection where i can help it. by using interfaces and coding against these i can do a lot of things that some would use reflection for.

But im a big fan of if it works, it works.

Also by using reflection you probably have something that can adapt fairly easily.

Ie the only objection most would have is fairly religious ... and if your performance is fine and the code is maintainable and clear .... who cares?

Edit: based on your edit i would indeed use interfaces to achieve what you want. Unless i misunderstand you.

Comment: I don't think the *only* objection is religious.  Being in C#, some of us *enjoy* static type safety. :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on your edit, it sounds like you are using reflection *purely* as a mechanism for *identifying* fields.  This is as opposed to dynamic behavior such as *looking up* the fields, which should be avoided when possible (since such lookups usually use strings which ruin static type safety).  Using `FieldInfo` to provide an identifier for a field is fairly harmless, though it does expose some internals (the info class) in a way that is not entirely ideal.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a good idea to stay away from Reflection when possible, but dont be afraid to resort to it when it provides a better or more flexible solution to your problem. The performance hit for anything but tight loop operations is likely to be minimal in the overall scheme of an application or Web Form request.

Just a good article to share about reflection -

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/a-defense-of-reflection-in-.net/

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use interfaces in my business layer and leave the reflection to my presentation layer. This is not an absolute but rather a guideline.