# How can i select string from constants in c#?

Tags: c#, constants

```
internal class DumbTable
{
     internal const string AC = "V2_AC";
     internal const string DG = "V2_DG"; 
     ......
}
```

I have a variable name **abc** and its value is "AC".

How can i select the values of const string whose names are based on **abc** value i.e. AC

Comment: where is `abc` in the given snippet

Comment: what do you mean by 'select'  can you show how you are currently trying to use those constants?

Comment: That we have to assume,isn't it?

Comment: yes, abc will be AC or DG

Comment: Please clarify your question. It currently makes no sense.

Comment: Please create an [mcve]

Comment: I am voting to close this since the question is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the initial question, prevoius answers and comments I think you could use a dictionary (a hashtable) like this:

```
// Just for simplicity.. in the real world you'd maybe use a property!
Dictionary<string, string> TablenamesDict = new Dictionary(string, string>();


// In your consturctor: Initialize dictionary
TablenamesDict.add('AC','V2_AC');
TablenamesDict.add('DG','V2_DG');
TablenamesDict.add('somekey','somevalue');
...


// You can use the dictionary like this:
string keyName = Getname();
string tableName = TablenamesDict[keyName];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this

```
string val1 = DumbTable.AC;// will give "V2_AC"
string val2 = DumbTable.DG;// will give "V2_DG"
```

Comment: no, if it is AC then only it will use like this DumbTable.AC.

Comment: Means it should depend on the abc value

Comment: abc = Getname();//returns AC,DG,
                string tablename = // if it is AC then V2_AC
                GetDumbData(tablename);

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this.

```
abc = Getname();
string tablename = GetTableName(abc);
...

public string GetTableName(string abc)
{
  if (abc == "AC")
   return DumbTable.AC;
  else if (abc == "AG")
   return DumbTable.DG;
  else
   return "";
}
```

I don't really understand your question.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any alternative way without using if or case

Comment: What you want is to access `variable's` value at run time and that `variable's` name will also compute at run time.I don't think there is any easy alternative **IN YOUR SITUATION**

Answer (score 0):

In the words of Jerry Maguire, Rafi, "help us help you". You need to write a fuller question for us to understand what you want.

I think you might be saying you have a string variable `abc` which can be assigned either the value `"AC"` or the value `"DG"`. You want to be able to use the value of `abc` to dictate whether you retrieve from `Dumbtable` the value of constant `AC` or `DC`.

There are better ways than the code below, but given we have so little to go on, you could try:

```
var dummy = new DumbTable();
string result;
if (abc == "AC")
{
    result = dummy.AC;
}
else
{
    result = dummy.DG;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also an interesting thing like **reflection**. Probably, that's the thing you are looking for. 
Reflection allows you to write code that can inspect various aspects about the code itself.

For example, take a look at this code:

```
string abc = "AC";

var field = typeof (DumbTable).GetField(abc, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

if (field == null) 
{
    // throw Exception, probably
} else {
    var value = field.GetValue(null);
}
```

**[`Type.GetField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e(v=vs.110).aspx)** method returns `FieldInfo` object for a found field, or returns `null` if no fields found with set `BindingFlags` was found.

**However,** reflection is the thing which, in my opinion, should be only used if no other approaches are suitable. There are several articles about it:

[Is it good practice to use reflection in your business logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924509/is-it-good-practice-to-use-reflection-in-your-business-logic)
[Why is the use of reflection in .NET recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458256/why-is-the-use-of-reflection-in-net-recommended)

In your case, using `switch` statement is the best way:

```
switch (abc)
{
    case "AC";
        break;
    case "DG";
        break;
    default;
        // throw Exception, probably
        break;
}
```